# How to implement Azure AD SSO with camunda

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, camunda

I want to implement Azure Active Directory SSO with Camunda.
Found some resources like -

https://github.com/finexioinc/camunda-azure-sso-boilerplate

and followed them
but after logging in, i am not able to view anything like cockpit/admin etc and getting 401 error after successful login.

Is there any step by step guide or fully functional boilerplate for the same or guide me towards right direction.

Couldn't get any help from camunda forum as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these tested examples for

web applications: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/azure-oauth2-cambpm-web

and REST API: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/azure-oauth2-cambpm-rest

They are created by Camunda Consulting and also based on later Camunda version (7.13) and Azure version than the example you referenced (7.12).

Comment: By using web applications: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/azure-oauth2-cambpm-web , i am getting errors on compile.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vivekkrkarn/3d9ffe926e75491590fd063f93e1baba

Comment: Have you followed the prerequisites in the readme and updated the application.yaml with the values that you have gathered from your Azure setup?

Comment: yes, followed their instructions and updated the application.yaml accordingly